# Service to recommend new songs based on those currently in iTunes

Tags: itunes

Is there an application that can look at the songs I have bought with iTunes and provide me with recommendations of new songs to buy?

Comment: I think iTunes provides relevant recommendations these days. Big data is the key here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As been previously said, there is a built-in feature of iTunes named 'Genius' that does exactly this. It can be accessed in two ways:

- Select the iTunes Store item from the source list to the left in the iTunes main window. When the store is visible, scroll down a bit to the section titled 'Genius recommendations', where you will find recommendations for new music to try based on what you've previously purchased.
- Select a song in the iTunes window, and click the button in the lower right corner that has a a square with a left-pointing arrow inside. This will display the Genius sidebar, which recommends new music based on this particular song in your library.

Comment: Thanks, I though that feature only put together playlists

Answer (score 3):

iTunes Genius feature. It's already built in with iTunes.

Comment: The problem with Genius is that is can only suggest songs when you click on a specific one... :-(

Comment: I'm quite sure that it can do song recommendations with playlists too.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant something that would recommend new songs for me to buy

Answer (score 1):

try [iLike](http://www.ilike.com/)